# Lamps don't seem to give off light in object mode

Tags: mesh, lighting

I played with the lamps earlier in the sculpt and they worked as expected. Tilt the light and the shadows followed accordingly. Then I wanted to get rid of it and I assume I clicked something I shouldn't have as now the light only shows in rendering. The issue follows me to new files and after uninstalling and reinstalling the program which seems odd. Is there a setting or option that I inadvertently clicked or did I just break it somehow?[image: Pink light just to make it obvious][image: Spot lights for variety]

Answer (score 1):

A friend found out what happened- apparently the viewport shading switched on me!
 I switched it to material and it was as what I was looking for.

[image: Viewport]